# Simple react render is not working

Tags: reactjs

Here I am trying to display a simple dropdown.I come to know `getInitialState` also not working.I spent some hours on it.Can you please explain it? Thank you.

```
var dropdown = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function() {
console.log('tr1');
return {
  data2:[] 
};
},

componentDidMount: function() {
console.log('tr2');
$.get(this.props.source, function(result) {  

  if (this.isMounted()) { 
    this.setState({          
      data2:result.data,

    });
  }
}.bind(this));
},



render:function() {
console.log('tr1');
console.log(this.state.data2);
return (

<div>

    <h3>Select portfolio </h3> <br/>

    <select onChange = {this.handleSelectChange}>
    <option>any-select</option>


    </select>

</div>

);
}
    });

ReactDOM.render(<dropdown source="http://improwised.cgc.com/portfolios?token=yR225Y"   />, document.getElementById('hello1'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dropdown` to `Dropdown`, because it is React component and should start from uppercase letter

[`Tags vs. React Components`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/25268/)